# why we use cursorposition function of qlineedit?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I was reading the work of `cursorposition` of `qlineedit` in documentation it was written that

> This property holds the current cursor position of this lineedit.
> setting the cursor position causes a repaint when appropriate.
> By default, this property contains a value of 0.

what does this lines mean.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor position is the index of the character in the displayed string that will be changed if you type something. Usually, it is indicated by a (blinking) vertical bar and advances as you type.
If the string is `Hello World`, and the cursor position is 3, then the line edit will look like `Hel|lo World`, and when you type, e.g., `x`, it will change to
`Helx|lo World`.

By default, the cursor is placed at the beginning of the string, i.e., at position zero (0).

If the cursor position changed, a repaint is usually required, since the line edit is supposed to look differently (the vertical bar has moved).
I'm not sure when a repaint would not be appropriate. Maybe if the cursor is not visible.